# Mongodb compound index not being used

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb index with close to 100k documents. On each document, there are the following 3 fields.

arrayX: [ObjectId]
someID: ObjectId
timestamp: Date

I have created a compound index for the 3 fields in that order.

When I try to then fire an aggregate query (written below in pseudocode), as

```
match(
  and(
    arrayX: (elematch: A),
    someId: Y
  )
)
sort (timestamp: 1)
```

it does not end up using the compound index.

The way I know this is when I use `.explain()`, the winningPlan stage is `FETCH`, the `inputStage` is `IXSCAN` and the `indexname` is `timestamp_1`
which means its only using the other single key index i created for the timestamp field.

What's interesting is that if I remove the sort stage, and keep everything the exact same, mongodb ends up using the compound index.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Multi-key indexes are not useful for sorting.  I would expect that a plan using the other index was listed in rejectedPlans.

If you run explain with the allPlansExecution option, the response will also show you the execution times for each plan, among other things.

Since the multi-key index can't be used for sorting the results, that plan would require a blocking sort stage.  This means that all of the matching documents must be retrieved and then sorted in memory before sending a response.

On the other hand, using the timestamp_1 index means that documents will be encountered in a presorted order while traversing the index.  The tradeoff here is that there is no blocking sort stage, but every document must be examined to see if it matches the query.

For data sets that are not huge, or when the query will match a significant fraction of the collection, the plan without a blocking sort will return results faster.

You might test creating another index on `{ someID:1, timestamp:1 }` as this might reduce the number of documents scanned while still avoiding the blocking sort.

The reason the compound index is selected when you remove the sort stage is because that stage probably accounts for the majority of the execution time.

The fields in the executionStats section of the explain output are explained in [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/index.html#executionstats).  Comparing the estimated execution times for each stage may help you determine where you can tune the queries.

Comment: You're right! When I replaced the array elematch in the query, with another field, and added a compound index with that field instead, the .explain() showed the compound index being used!

That said, there were no rejected plans in the original query, even when I ran with the allPlansExecution option.

Answer (score 0):

I am using documents like this (based on the question post) for discussion:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  fld: "One",
  arrayX: [ ObjectId("5e44f9ed221e963909537848"), ObjectId("5e44f9ed221e963909537849") ],
  someID: ObjectId("5e44f9e7221e963909537845"),
  timestamp: ISODate("2020-02-12T01:00:00.0Z")
}
```

**The Indexes:**

I created two indexes, as mentioned in the question post:

`{ timestamp: 1 }` and `{ arrayX:1, someID:1, timestamp:1 }`

**The Query:**

```
db.test.find( 
  { 
      someID: ObjectId("5e44f9e7221e963909537845"), 
      arrayX: ObjectId("5e44f9ed221e963909537848")
  } 
).sort( { timestamp: 1 } )
```

In the above query I am *not* using `$elemMatch`. A query filter using `$elemMatch` with *single field equality condition* can be written *without* the `$elemMatch`. From [$elemMatch Single Query Condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html#single-query-condition):

> If you specify a single query predicate in the $elemMatch expression,
>   $elemMatch is not necessary.

**The Query Plan:**

I ran the query with `explain`, and found that the query uses the `arrayX_1_someID_1_timestamp_1`index. The *index is used* for the *filter* as well as the *sort* operations of the query.

Sample plan details:

```
"winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                        "arrayX" : 1,
                        "someID" : 1,
                        "timestamp" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "arrayX_1_someID_1_timestamp_1",
...
```

The IXSCAN specifies that the query uses the index. The FETCH stage specifies that the document is retrieved for getting other details using the index id. This means that both the query's filter as well as the sort use the index. The way to know that sort uses an index is the plan will *not* have a SORT stage - as in this case.

**Reference:**

From [Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index):

> An index can support sort operations on a non-prefix subset of the
>   index key pattern. To do so, the query must include equality
>   conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys.

Comment: Great point regarding the elemMatch, that makes perfect sense! Thanks.

Although when I tried that exact same query over my db, it still doesn't end up using the compound index, and uses the timestamp index for sort instead.

I'm wondering if its something to do with the distribution of records I have.

My db has around 130k records and for the query I'm testing, about 38k match the query itself, which then need to be sorted by the timestamp. Can you try that and see if it changes anything in your test as well?

Comment: I only tried with a small set of documents. I may not be able to simulate your environment. I am working with MongoDB version 4.2 and the queries are run from Mongo Shell. Yes, the amount of data might and other indexes can influence index selection. Making sure that the correct indexes are applied to the query also requires some trials (and all is not science and math; some art is involved).

Comment: That said, sometimes an index may not be applied as it is not loaded into the memory (or as it is not part of the working set). Also, by using the [cursor.hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/index.html) you can make the query optimizer to apply an index on the query (though it is not considered a best practice).

Comment: good to know, I'm running my mongodb instances on mlab, which I guess is still on 3.6.12 (MMAPv1). which may be what's causing it.

How would I know if the index has been loaded into memory or is part of the working set?

Let me try to load the entire db on my local mongodb instance which is running on 4.2 and see if I notice the same behavior.

Comment: ok, just tried running this against my local mongodb which actually is 3.6.8 and the compound index does get used correctly for the exact same query, over the exact same set of documents. 
The only difference I can think of then is that my local mongodb is using wiredTiger as the engine whereas mlab uses MMAPv1